# Merge array of complex objects by using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js, lodash

I'm new to Lodash and trying to solve this problem but could find a good way to do it.

I have an array of objects return back from the database. The data is structured as below:

```
var data = [{
    index: 1,
    Aoo: "a1",
    Boo: 'b2',
}, {
    index: 1,
    Aoo: "a2",
    Boo: 'b2',
}, {
    index: 2,
    Aoo: "a3",
    Boo: 'b3',
}];
```

I want to first group the objects by index, then group the attribute "Aoo" and "Boo" and put it in an array attribute called `param`.

```
var result = [{
        index: 1,
        param: [{
            Aoo: 'A1',
            Boo: 'B1'
        },{
            Aoo: 'A2',
            Boo: 'B2',
        }]
    }, {
        index: 2,
        param: [{
            Aoo: 'A3',
            Boo: 'B3'
        }]
   }
]
```

I can do it manually but I want to make the most use of Lodash's functionality. Right now I only know I can achieve the first step of grouping by using `_.groupBy('index')` and I am stuck at what to do next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there. Here is how this can be done using lodash

```js
var data = [{
    index: 1,
    Aoo: "a1",
    Boo: 'b2',
}, {
    index: 1,
    Aoo: "a2",
    Boo: 'b2',
}, {
    index: 2,
    Aoo: "a3",
    Boo: 'b3',
}];

var result = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy('index')
  .map((value, key) => {
    return {
      index: Number(key), //the index was transformed into a string, this will make it a number again.
      param: _.map(value, o => _.omit(o, 'index'))//do not include the index key from the previous objects
    }
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The second part is, admittedly, slightly trickier than the grouping, but not by much. Since indexing gives you this structure:

```js
{
  "1": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "Aoo": "a1",
      "Boo": "b2"
    },
    {
      "index": 1,
      "Aoo": "a2",
      "Boo": "b2"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "index": 2,
      "Aoo": "a3",
      "Boo": "b3"
    }
  ]
}
```

All you really want to do is go over it, make each key be the `index` property and then you are left with an array of the inital objects. Each needs to be transformed by removing the `index` key and that will be assigned to the `param` value. This is done in one go using `.map`. Unfortunately, it's not as pretty as it could look but I think that's the best you can do with the base version of Lodash.

If you want to select a specific subset of the keys, instead of "all but **index**", then you can use `_.pick` instead of `_.omit` to do it. Here is how this would look:

```js
var data = [{
    index: 1,
    Aoo: "a1",
    Boo: 'b2',
    Coo: "c1"
}, {
    index: 1,
    Aoo: "a2",
    Boo: 'b2',
    Coo: "c2"
}, {
    index: 2,
    Aoo: "a3",
    Boo: 'b3',
    Coo: "c3"
}];

var result = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy('index')
  .map((value, key) => {
    return {
      index: Number(key), //the index was transformed into a string, this will make it a number again.
      param: _.map(value, o => _.pick(o, ['Aoo', 'Boo']))//do not include the index key from the previous objects
    }
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

So we get the same result even though there is an extra key in the data.

Comment: Was a few seconds behind posting literally a character for character answer  :)

Comment: thank you for the fast response! I do have a follow up question. What if i have more attributes that doesn't want to get include? Do i need to map it one by one? for example: `{Aoo: "a", Boo: "b", Coo: "c", Doo: "d"}` and I only want to combine `Boo` and `Coo`? thanks!

Comment: If you only want to select specific properties use `_.pick()` instead of `_.omit()`, since it does the opposite.

Comment: @CocoHot I've added an example of how that would look.